# Can viewvc be configured with a context root with svn

Tags: svn

> I have configured viewvc for svn repository browsing and is working with https://svn.example.com/viewvc/reponame. Now my requirement is to make viewvc work with a context root svn.
>   like https://svn.example.com/SVN/viewvc/reponame. i tried this but no luck. 
>   Help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to achieve what you want by configuring a proxy / reverse proxy pair in your web server. The way to do it depends on the web server you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the documentation](http://viewvc.tigris.org/source/browse/%2acheckout%2a/viewvc/branches/1.1.x/INSTALL).  If you are using Apache HTTPD to serve ViewVC, then there should be a line in your httpd.conf like:

```
ScriptAlias /viewvc <VIEWVC_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY>/bin/cgi/viewvc.cgi
```

Simply changing this to:

```
ScriptAlias /SVN/viewvc <VIEWVC_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY>/bin/cgi/viewvc.cgi
```

should change the URL from https://svn.example.com/viewvc/reponame to https://svn.example.com/SVN/viewvc/reponame.

However, if there is already something serving the URL https://svn.example.com/SVN/... (for example if you have Subversion itself serving at that URL), then you can't also have ViewVC there.